Struggling to Get Jupyter Python Kernel Working in VSCodeium on Arch Linux - Should I Switch Back to Windows?
I've been facing issues with getting the Python kernel to work in Jupyter notebooks on VSCodeium (my Arch Linux setup) for the past 3 days. Despite managing to start the kernel after much troubleshooting, I am still encountering errors (as shown in the attached screenshots). I’ve tried everything I can, but it seems like the setup process is never-ending, and I haven't written a single line of code yet.
At this point, I’m feeling really frustrated, and I’m considering switching back to Windows. Is there any quick solution or better approach I should try before giving up? How can I resolve this issue and get back to coding?
Here are the relevant details:

Arch Linux is my current OS.
I’m using VSCodeium for development.
Jupyter Notebook is installed with the Python kernel, but the kernel won’t load correctly.
I’ve tried updating packages, reinstalling extensions, and setting up the environment multiple times.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Screenshots:


